# javascript scope error with geoxml3 afterParse callback

Tags: javascript, geoxml3

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'placemarks' of undefined" at Object.useData [as afterParse]

here is a simplified snippet:

```
<script>
    var map;
    var myParser;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
    myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,

    afterParse: useData
});
myParser.parse('./my.kml');
function useData() {
    var someVar = myParser.docs[0].placemarks.length;
    //yada yada
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The after parse function gets passed the `docs` array as its argument.  When it is called you can do this:

```
function useData(doc) {
  console.log("parsed " + doc[0].placemarks.length + " placemarks");
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "parsed " + doc[0].placemarks.length + " placemarks";
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nbo670zr/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var myParser;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
  myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    afterParse: useData
  });
  myParser.parseKmlString(kmlStr);

  function useData(doc) {
    console.log("parsed " + doc[0].placemarks.length + " placemarks");
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "parsed " + doc[0].placemarks.length + " placemarks";
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
var kmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><Document><name>Massachusetts Cities</name><Folder><Placemark><name>Boston</name><description>Boston is the capital of and largest city in Massachusetts. The Boston Massacre and the Boston Tea Party occurred in Boston and led to the American Revolution.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.05977300312775</longitude><latitude>42.35843100531216</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>-2.107386233340164e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>34426.00143998101</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin9</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.05977300312775,42.35843100531217,3.1482280535562</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Worcester</name><description>Worcester is known as the &quot;Heart of the Commonwealth&quot; due to its location in central Massachusetts, thus, a heart is the official symbol of the city.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.80229299737233</longitude><latitude>42.2625930065606</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>1.76716070878667e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>17233.50055269895</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.80229299737233,42.26259300656061,145.2545892926215</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Springfield</name><description>Historically the first Springfield in America.</description><LookAt><longitude>-72.58981099924824</longitude><latitude>42.10148299778795</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>5.040065975981161e-010</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>17277.36855774167</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin6</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-72.58981099984295,42.10148300097482,39.44687703020819</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Lowell</name><description>Lowell is known as the birthplace of the industrial revolution in the United States.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.31617200184621</longitude><latitude>42.63342499640326</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>-1.250482781337603e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>8564.451680780059</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin3</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.31617200184621,42.63342499640325,32.71923637446179</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Cambridge</name><description>Cambridge is home to two internationally prominent universities, Harvard University and the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.10965300713373</longitude><latitude>42.37264000434871</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>-4.807793248148562e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>8600.20020650975</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin2</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.10965300713372,42.37264000434871,7.159466020276252</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Brockton</name><description>Brockton is sometimes referred to as the &quot;City of Champions&quot; due to the success of native boxers Rocky Marciano and Marvin Hagler.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.01837899995951</longitude><latitude>42.08343399824823</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>2.712218004618013e-011</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>8639.699317635228</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.0183789999595,42.08343399824823,30.29967761376449</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>New Bedford</name><description>New Bedford is nicknamed &quot;The Whaling City&quot; because during the 19th century it was one of the most important whaling ports in the world.</description><LookAt><longitude>-70.93420500203244</longitude><latitude>41.63621500187266</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>-1.350326753898106e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>17403.47639378627</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin4</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-70.93420500203244,41.63621500187266,24.75716633283448</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Fall River</name><description>Fall River is known for Battleship Cove which has the world&apos;s largest collection of World War II naval vessels.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.15504499654021</longitude><latitude>41.70149101206891</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>2.301640200787889e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>17385.8377123415</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin7</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.15504499654021,41.70149101206891,23.26129426529637</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Lynn</name><description>Lynn is about 7 miles north of downtown Boston.</description><LookAt><longitude>-70.94949399981969</longitude><latitude>42.46676300410375</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>1.217166471049273e-010</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>8587.326697933368</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin5</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-70.94949399981969,42.46676300410375,14.89168526609486</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>Quincy</name><description>Quincy is the birthplace of U.S. Presidents John Adams and John Quincy Adams.</description><LookAt><longitude>-71.00227000742845</longitude><latitude>42.25287699598879</latitude><altitude>0</altitude><heading>-4.994952988379282e-009</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>17236.11617372477</range><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode></LookAt><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin8</styleUrl><Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>-71.00227000742845,42.25287699598879,14.5549973299613</coordinates></Point></Placemark></Folder></Document></kml>';
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. typos fixed in the snippet. the difference between what I was doing before using 'async defer' and the rewritten synchronous version is that I seem to have to define the afterParse function explicitly with an array name 'function useData(docs)' whereas before I was using 'function useData()'. Additionally using the parser name 'myParser.docs[0].placemarks.length' doesn't work and I have to use 'docs[0].placemarks.length'. Why can I no longer use the global var myParser in the afterParse function?